Bsc full node out of sync perdiodically
I have full nodes on BSC and BSC Testnet.
Periodically, every 1 or 2 months, both nodes go out of sync.
To resolve this, I need to update Geth to the latest version and restart the nodes.
A simple restart without updating Geth isn't sufficient.
Has anyone else experienced this issue?
There is not out of disk/memory error and others. just stops syncing and geth needs to be updated. it seems strange to me that a full node will just stop syncing after 1month.
